# Fine Uploader cannot draw thumbnail from amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3, cors, fine-uploader

I have a form with a Fine Uploader and I am loading an initial file list (as described [here](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/session.html))

For the list of initial files I am also returning the `thumbnailUrl` which points to my files in Amazon's S3.

Now I see that Fine Uploader is actually making an HTTP request to S3 and gets a 200 OK but the thumbnail is not displayed and this is what I see in the console:

```
[Fine Uploader 5.1.3] Attempting to update thumbnail based on server response.
[Fine Uploader 5.1.3] Problem drawing thumbnail!
```

Response from my server:

```
{"name": 123, "uuid": "...", "thumbnailUrl": "...."}
```

Now Fine Uploader makes a GET request to S3 to the URL specified in the thumbnailUrl property. The request goes like this:

curl "HERE_IS_MY_URL" -H "Host: s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com" -H "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0" -H "Accept: image/png,image/*;q=0.8,*/*;q=0.5" -H "Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5" --compressed -H "DNT: 1" -H "Referer: http://localhost:9000/edititem/65" -H "Origin: http://localhost:9000" -H "Connection: keep-alive" -H "Cache-Control: max-age=0"

Response: 200 OK with Content-Type application/octet-stream

Is there any configuration option for Fine Uploader that I am missing? Could it be that this is a CORS-related issue?

Comment: Please add more information, such as details of the specific GET request (for the image) according to the browser dev tools _and_ the initial file list data you are returning.

Comment: @RayNicholus I updated the question with some more information

Comment: The content type is application/octet-stream? That doesn't sound like an image at all. Sounds like your server isn't providing an actual image.

Comment: The content type application/octet-stream comes as part of the response from Amazon's S3, not from my server

Comment: Then the response from S3 doesn't appear to be an image. Without a sample URL from your S3 bucket, I'm not sure how I can help further. Otherwise, you can take a look at Fine Uploader's debug logs and/or step through the code to see what it is failing on.

Comment: What about this one for example https://s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/mb-items-dev/131O9hcI8YaL._SX425_.jpg

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82539/discussion-between-anton-and-ray-nicholus).

Comment: Are you seeing any CORS erorrs in the browser JS console? I would expect this to be the problem. I'm certainly seeing them in Chrome, but I'm not sure what CORS rules you've set on your bucket.

Comment: Using Firefox I cannot see any CORS errors. But on the other hand I haven't changed the CORS rules on my bucket so maybe this is why the request is not going through

Comment: What are you seeing in Chrome, and what are the CORS rules on your bucket?

Comment: I'm not seeing CORS errors in FF either, but am in Chrome. Yet another reason why I avoid firefox at all costs. I'll write up an answer since i'm quite sure this is a CORS issue.

Comment: FYI: I just did a small check and created a CORS policy on the bucket to allow localhost:9000 (as this is the origin - see my post) - then the request went throught and the image was returned. Waiting for your answer, will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fine Uploader loads thumbnails at the URL returned by your initial file list endpoint using an ajax request (`XMLHttpRequest`) in modern browsers. It does this so it can scale and properly orient the image preview.

You'll need a CORS rule on your S3 bucket that allows JS access via a GET request. It will look something like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>http://example.com</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

Of course, you may need to allow other origins/headers/methods depending on whatever else you are doing with S3.

Comment: This was indeed the solution to the problem - see also the discussion in the comments of the original post. Thanks a lot!