# Fine Uploader file ID is always 0, how to change it?

Tags: fine-uploader

I am using Fine Uploader's feature "initial file list". After some [initial troubles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254374/fine-uploader-cannot-draw-thumbnail-from-amazon-s3) I am now able to display my files and want to handle the deletion of uploaded items.

According to http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/session.html my server-side should provide a JSON array with `Object`s containing at least name and uuid (I am using the Simple mode of Fine Uploader).

As you can see from the log below, the UUID property is handled without problems, I am receiving it on the server side and deleting the file successfully.

The problem comes from the fact that after a successful deletion I want to do something else on the client side and that is why I listed to the `deleteComplete` event like this:

```
.on('deleteComplete', function (event, id, xhr, isError) {
            if (!isError) {
                console.log("reducing the uploaded items");
                .... // do something here
            }
```

Now the `id` parameter is `0` which is a blocker for me because I have to use it for further processing. I guess the `0` comes from the submitted delete request before.

So what I am looking for is a way to somehow tell Fine Uploader what my id is. I guess if I am able to do it correctly when filling the initial file list then it will be correctly propagated to the `deleteComplete` method.

Output from Fine Uploader when I load the page with an initial file list and delete one of the files afterwards:

```
...
"[Fine Uploader 5.1.3] Attempting to update thumbnail based on server response."
"[Fine Uploader 5.1.3] Detected valid file button click event on file '7a5a2ebd-f7d3-40a1-b9da-cde5fc9307c6', ID: 0."
"[Fine Uploader 5.1.3] Submitting delete file request for 0"
"[Fine Uploader 5.1.3] Sending DELETE request for 0"
"[Fine Uploader 5.1.3] Delete request for '7a5a2ebd-f7d3-40a1-b9da-cde5fc9307c6' has succeeded."
....
```

Comment: Why does the id matter to you?

Comment: Let's say that after a successful delete of the file I would like to inform the user about the 'just deleted file' by also stating the ID. I would also like to use the id as a value for one of my input fields..

Comment: You can't change the id. This is a value fine uploader sets, and i don't see a reason to change this. The user likely doesn't care about the file id anyway since it has no meaning to them, so i would suggest simply not displaying it.

Comment: Is there any way to tell Fine Uploader how to get at least my uuid from the id or something similar? I cannot really accept the statement that my user does not care about the ID - it could be a power user which really needs the information.

Comment: I was typing faster that looking for ... `$('#fine-uploader').fineUploader('getUuid', id);` will actually return my uuid given the internal fine uploader id so I can work with that one

Comment: Yes there certainly is [a way to get the uuid from an id](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getUuid). Please take a look at the docs site for similar questions in the future.

Comment: Feel free to add this as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As seen in the comments, it turned out that the `id` field is something that Fine Uploader manages internally and manipulating this is not possible and not wanted. As all of my items have their own `uuid` field I was able to use that one for further processing and distinguishing between the deleted files.

In order to retrieve the `uuid` field for a provided `id` one can use the [get uuid from an id method](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getUuid) which goes like this:

```
var uuid = $('#fine-uploader').fineUploader('getUuid', id);
```