# Unable to view image on thumbnail in fine-uploader

Tags: javascript, jquery, fine-uploader

Hi I am working on upload feature which has been done successfully using fine uploader, but for new functionality for edit i searched for same plugin and found that session can handle this functionality.

but i am not getting view of image in fine uploader section as below is the view i am getting.

[image]

I am passing name,uuid and thumbnailUrl as response.

**Edited:**
At Server Side:

```
 List<PropertyImageEntity> propertyImageEntity=propertyService.getImagesUrlNames(Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("id")),Constant.PROP_VAL);
       for(PropertyImageEntity propertyImagesDetails: propertyImageEntity)
         {
            ImageDataResponse imageResponseData=new ImageDataResponse();
            imageResponseData.setName(propertyImagesDetails.getFilename());
            String test=String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID());
            imageResponseData.setUuid(this.uuid);
            imageResponseData.setId(String.valueOf(propertyImagesDetails.getImageid()));
            imageResponseData.setSize(propertyImagesDetails.getSize());
            imageResponseData.setStatus("upload successful");
            imageResponseData.setThumbnailUrl(propertyImagesDetails.getUrl());
            imageResponse.add(imageResponseData);
         }
```

at client side:

```
var manualUploader1 = new qq.FineUploader(
        {
            element : document
                    .getElementById('fine-uploader-manual-trigger1'),
            template : 'qq-template-manual-trigger1',
            request : {
                endpoint : '/server/uploads?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}&id=${id}'
            },
            thumbnails : {
                placeholders : {
                    waitingPath : '../assets/js/property/fileupload/placeholders/waiting-generic.png',
                    notAvailablePath : '../assets/js/property/fileupload/placeholders/not_available-generic.png'
                }
            },
            validation : {
                allowedExtensions : [ 'png', 'jpeg', 'jpg' , 'gif'],
                itemLimit : 6,
                sizeLimit : 100000000
            },
            autoUpload : false,
            debug : true,
            callbacks: {
                onError: function(id, name, errorReason, xhrOrXdr) {

                        $("#errorMsg4").html(errorReason);
                }
            },
            session: {
                endpoint: '/server/get?id=${id}',
                params: {},
                customHeaders: {},
                refreshOnReset: true
            },
            messages: {
                typeError: jQuery.i18n.prop("invalid.extention.error"),
                sizeError: jQuery.i18n.prop("upload.filesize.error"),
                noFilesError: jQuery.i18n.prop("nofiles.toupload.error"),
                tooManyItemsError: jQuery.i18n.prop("toomany.items.error"),
                retryFailTooManyItems: jQuery.i18n.prop("retry.fail.error")
            }
        });

qq(document.getElementById("trigger-upload1")).attach("click",
        function() {
        $("#errorMsg4").html("");
            manualUploader1.uploadStoredFiles();
        });
```

but response for image url in console showing 200 ok.

**Response:**

```
[{"name":"b.png","uuid":"e3a5581e-aee9-4b8d-813f-63e0d400c9bc","thumbnailUrl":"http://192.168.1.68/html/1465290007617b.png","id":"84","size":26507,"status"
:null}]
```

**Console Log:**

[image]

Comment: What messages are you seeing in the browser console?

Comment: And you will need to show your code

Comment: @RayNicholus i have updated post\

Comment: This time update it with all of your client side code and the browser console messages, please

Comment: @RayNicholus i have updated response and client code\

Comment: @RayNicholus sorry for late response. i am mostly a backend developer so confused what you were asking. i have updated full console log in image format..

Comment: Thanks for that. The thumbnail is being served from `http://192.168.1.68/`. What is the exact URL of the page hosting Fine Uploader?

Comment: @RayNicholus thanks for your reply, above problem is solved i gone through your answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254374/fine-uploader-cannot-draw-thumbnail-from-amazon-s3 and found the problem was in cors support. i just added cors support to my local apache and it works charm..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above problem was solved by adding cors headers in apache2.conf.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Thanks to @Ray for his answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254374/fine-uploader-cannot-draw-thumbnail-from-amazon-s3) post.